# Why are references not copyable?

Tags: c++, reference, copy

Why are references not copy-able?
I'm just struggling to think clearly right now. 
Why wouldn't you be able to copy a reference and up end with another reference to the same object? Is this not a copy of a reference?

I feel like there's something super obvious i'm missing.

Comment: What do you mean with words *references not copy-able*? Here is the example of copyable reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893624/why-is-the-class-holding-a-reference-copyable

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. You can't assign  a reference (`int test=42; int test2 = 24; int & testr = test; testr = test2;` goes boom), but something like `int test=42; int & testr = test; int & testc = testr;` works just fine.

Comment: They are copyable. They're not re-assignable.

Comment: The super obvious thing you're missing is a [mcve]

Comment: @user4581301 "goes boom" isn't terribly accurate. More like "compiles, but doesn't do what you may think". `testr = test2;` is effectively synonymous with `test = test2;`, which certainly won't go "boom".

Comment: After you bind a reference, whatever you do to it, you do to the original. If you copy it, you copy the original.

Comment: @Galik "*If you copy it, you copy the original.*" - that is not true. Sure, if you read/write a value via a reference, you read/write the original. But you can certainly copy a reference without copying the original object  it refers to. Unless you mean if you copy a reference, whatever you do to the copy also applies to the original reference, not the original object being referred to.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "copying" a reference is meaningless in `C++`. They do not exist as objects in their own right like pointers do. After a reference is bound, its *identifier* simply identifies the original object. It is another name for it. So making a copy from that identifier copies the original object.

Comment: @Galik Copying references is meaningful in the sense that a reference can be use to copy initialize another one: `int i = 42; int& a = i; int& b = a;`.

Comment: @juanchopanza That's not a copy. That is initializing a new reference to the original object. All the reference does is supply *type information*. References themselves are not entities to be "copied", they are merely a (type laden) *alias* to the original object.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think you may be thinking of references like pointers, which they are not.

Comment: @Galik No, I'm not doing that.

Answer (score 2):

In c++,declaring a named variable as a reference, that is, an **alias** to an already-existing object or function.

That is to say,any operation on the reference equals to operations on the orinal object refereced by you.

Therefore,once you write something like:

```
int foo=1;
int &bar=foo;
int a;
a=bar;//it's actually copying the foo,bar is just a alias.
```

So copying the reference itself is just copying the original object.

As a supplement, once there exists a class member of  reference type,the implicit default  **copy/move assignment** will be `=deleted`.  Because if it's allowed,after the copy assignment,the class member of reference type will not chage its orinally referecing object, **which is not what we actually want and probably cause ambiguity .**

However ,the **copy/move constructor** is allowed,because they are just initializing,not copying，which does not cause ambiguity.

Comment: "So copying the reference itself is just copying the original object" well, `int i = 42; int& a = i; int& b = a;` copying the reference is not copying the original object in this case.

Comment: You also seem to be mixing up copy and assignment.

Comment: `int&b=a` is not coping,it's just binding a reference to `a` in you case,which is also the initializing of `b`.

Comment: it is copying references.

Comment: @juanchopanza Does the standard says it's copying somewhere?I think it's just initialization.

Comment: initialization by copy construction

Comment: @juanchopanza no,`int&b=a` does not have copy construction.

Comment: In my example `a` is a reference.